# how do i get array name and echo it?

Tags: php

my php

```
if($user){

    try{
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $params = array('next' => 'website' );
        $logout =$facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
        $_SESSION['User']=$user_profile;
        foreach ($user_profile['education'] as $education) { // <-ERROR HERE
            if ($education['type'] == "College") {
                $college = $education;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(empty($college)) {
    echo "College information was not found!";
} else {
    // var_dump($college);
    $_SESSION['type'] = $college;
    print_r($college);
}
```

page return

```
Array ( [school] => Array ( [id] => 156029264583245 [name] => Universiti Tunku Abdul Rahman ) [type] => College )
```

i tried so many way to get it out , but none of them is working.they all return php error , my intention is echo the name of the school and store it into $SESSION. but i cant even get the echo the school name only. what am i going to do get the array data ? thank you

tried this also

```
 $college = json_decode($education, true);
         echo $college[1]["name"];
```

not working.

Comment: What PHP error are you getting?

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: is not about starting the session , i cant even echo the inside array name , i keep getting tones of error. thank you for helping.

Comment: I don't see any call to `json_decode()` on that line.

Comment: That comment should be posted below the answer. And maybe you should change the title so it doesn't mention the session, since that seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: i only wanted to store the array name into session , not the all the array. i have edit my question , i have tried kind a lot way to get it.

Comment: Dump the response and see what you are getting.

Comment: Whats the Content of `$user_Profile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Arrays are Zero based therefore to get the First Objekt you Need `[0]` and not `[1]`

```
 echo $college[0]["name"];
```

or you go namebased:

```
echo $college['school']['name'];
```

Comment: answer is given 1 Times before.

Comment: @ElefantPhace, Soproni's answer came first.

Comment: My Answer came first then Sporoni did and then I edited and then your came

Answer (score 0):

```
Array ( [school] => Array ( [id] => 156029264583245 [name] => Universiti Tunku Abdul Rahman ) [type] => College )
```

if this is already what you get then you can simply,

```
echo $college['school']['name'];
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this it will work :**

```
echo $college['school']['name'];
```

it will echo the name of the school.

Comment: What answer was given 2 Times before

Comment: @CherryPohShuLin, If you find it useful please upvote the answer.